# Tarantool blocks for operations, if error occurs inside box.begin()...box.commit() block

Tags: lua, tarantool

If error occurs inside box.begin()...box.commit() block, Tarantool box blocks for operations untill you manually execute box.commit()

For example, I provide incorrect data without one of fields to my function:

```
replace = function(space, data)
    local id = data[1][1]
    box.begin()
    my_module.delete(space, id)
    local response = my_module.insert(space, data)
    box.commit()
    return response
end
```

Inside of my_module.insert() it will encount an error, so execution of replace() will be aborted before execution of box.commit().

Later, if i call replace() again with another data, it won`t be able to execute box.begin() because of previously open transaction.

pcall(my_module.insert()) wasn`t able to catch an error.

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

There's a handy function for it - `box.atomic`

I suggest the following implementation:

```
replace = function(space, data)
    return box.atomic(function()
        local id = data[1][1]
        my_module.delete(space, id)
        return my_module.insert(space, data)
    end)
end
```

> pcall(my_module.insert()) wasn't able to catch an error.

`pcall` catches all errors. The error isn't caught probably because it occurs earlier on the delete operation.

By the way, Tarantool has inline operations for replace:

https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/reference/reference_lua/box_space_index/#box-space-replace